# What is the best way to document old complex SQL tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

we have a developer retiring this year and we are trying to make sure we have the knowledge to continue business as usual. There are tons of complex tables that tie into code/other tables, with a lot of poor acronyms that I want to document so we know where to look for each table and column. What I'm wondering is if there is a good software/method that would allow me to tie this nasty spider web of data together so it is easy to look up what these rows do in the future and where to look when we need to modify the information.

Comment: One thing I'd add to Bill's far-reaching answer: for things like data dictionaries and systems of acronyms and similar, it can be useful to store these in a structured way, rather than simply recording them freeform in a natural language document. This doesn't just make the information more usable, but it can also be useful for automatically reconciling the documentation to the database as things change over time (for example, for checking that all objects have coverage in the documentation).

Comment: Each column in a table definition can have a comment up to 1024 chars long. I found useful to store a link here pointing to the certain chapter of the whole table description.

Comment: @Kondybas Yeah, it seems like that may be the best way to document columns for now.

Comment: How old is the hardware?  The OS and Database?  It may be time to start over.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a specialized documentation tool for documenting databases. I recommend using whatever text editor you feel most productive with.

The other thing that is very important is to make sure everyone who needs the information knows how to find the document, after you write it all up. Most companies these days have either a Wiki of some kind, or Google Drive, or some other kind of cloud storage or shared fileserver.

I would approach it by making a prioritized list of tables in the database.

Some tables are more or less obvious, e.g. `countries` undoubtedly lists countries of the world. Put these at the end of your prioritized list. If your coworker leaves before getting to document these tables, there is less impact.

For each of the tables in the "high priority" subset, add a section to your document. Include in this section:

- Name of the table
- Purpose of the table, as briefly as possible
- What code in your application(s) read the table?
- What code in your application(s) update the table?
- Is the table read from or written to by multiple applications, or just one application?
- Expected size of the table, and expected growth rate.
- Data retention policy (if it fills up, how to decide what to delete? if data are archived instead of deleted, where are they stored?)
- Does the table contain any sensitive data, and if so, what's the policy for keeping it secure?
- Columns of the table: names, data types, expected values, what code reads/writes the values, etc.
- Does the table have any triggers?
- Is the table referenced in any views or stored routines?

Besides written documentation, consider designing an Entity-Relationship Diagram (ER Diagram). This is to illustrate the relationships between tables. MySQL Workbench is free and does a reasonable job at this. DBeaver or other non-free tools may also work for you. Even general-purpose drawing tools like OmniGraffle can be used, and there may exist some templates for ER Diagram design.

Don't feel obligated to represent the whole schema in a single ER Diagram. Most production schemas are too complex for that, and the connecting lines will get too over-crowded. I would expect 3 to 6 diagrams, each covering a subset of the whole schema, would be more useful.

In addition to the database schema, you should get your retiring coworker to document operational details about how the databases are managed. For example (the following is not intended to be a comprehensive list, just what I can think of):

- Are there any utility scripts or scheduled jobs in your environment that are not part of the application(s), but are needed to maintain the database? For example: backups, archiving, reindexing, generating reports, updating summary tables, etc. How often do these tasks run? What server do they run on? Who has access to them? Is all the code for these utilities committed to source control, and if so, in which repo? Is the usage of these utilities documented? How are automated tasks monitored to make sure they continue to work (in other words, would anyone be notified if they fail to work)?
- Document the infrastructure. How many database servers do you have? What are the server sizes? What size and type of storage? Do you have failover servers, and if so, how does failover get invoked? Do you have replicas? How do applications use the replicas? Do you have replicas in another region? How are these accessed?
- Document the security policies. Who has access to the database? How is access granted or revoked (for example if someone leaves the company)? How are passwords or certificates renewed? If any data is encrypted, who is responsible for the encryption keys? How are keys kept safe, or passed to a new responsible person if the primary person leaves?
- How are schema changes (aka *migrations*) performed? Do you use an off-the-shelf schema change management tool such as Flyway or Liquibase or Rails Migrations or SQLAlchemy, or others? Or a homegrown solution? Are all schema changes represented by files in source control? Is the production database instance exactly the same with respect to schema as all the test or development instances? How is this ensured?
- What monitoring system do you use? What alerting system do you use? What specific alerts are configured for the database? Do you have documented Standard Operating Procedures (SOPs) for each alert type (i.e. what should the oncall person do if any given alert happens)?
- Database configuration file (e.g. `my.cnf`). There may be dozens of custom options configured for the database server. What are they? Why did these options need to be customized, instead of using their default values? Why were the specific values chosen? Are the configuration files committed in a source control repo? If so, where?
- What version of the database software do you use? What is the policy for keeping up with new versions? How to perform an upgrade?
- Are there any procedures or utilities for creating a clone of the production database instance for testing or development purposes? How are these utilities used? Where are they? Are they in source control?

Chapter 24 in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/) is about documenting databases.